# How to generate a random whole positive number in Javascript with no specific range

Tags: javascript, random

I need a method that generates a positive whole number, any number.
Couldn't found any answer that specify those exact requirements - any positive && whole number.

Basically I'm looking for something like that:

```js
const randomNumber = getWholePositiveNum();
```

Comment: You could use an existing random integer function with `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` as the max.

Comment: You've got to have an upper bound, either defined by the type or by some other max value. It is of course impossible to have a *well distributed* random value if you don't know what to distribute the value over. Otherwise to comply it would just output infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The subtle crypto interface provides a method. Node.js includes this library as well. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues)

> #### Crypto: getRandomValues() method
>
> The Crypto.getRandomValues() method lets you get cryptographically
> strong random values. The array given as the parameter is filled with
> random numbers (random in its cryptographic meaning).
>
> To guarantee enough performance, implementations are not using a truly
> random number generator, but they are using a pseudo-random number
> generator seeded with a value with enough entropy. The pseudo-random
> number generator algorithm (PRNG) may vary across user agents, but is
> suitable for cryptographic purposes.

```js
console.log(self.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found:

```js
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) + 1)
```

- `Math.random()` provides an evenly distributed decimal between 0 and 1
- Multiplying by `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` scales it to the desired range - max safe integer value in JS, which is 9007199254740991
- `Math.floor()` converts it to an integer (whole)
- Adding 1 makes the range start at 1 instead of 0